# Algorithms and Data structure

Tags: algorithm

MaximumPairwiseProduct

```
    for(int i =0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j =i+1; j< n; j++){
         ................
         ................
        }
    }
```

so I was wondering what will be the value of `j` at the when `i = n-1`. Thank you

Comment: Try stepping through it with a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the processor computes `i` as `n-1` value, `j` doesn't exist at all. The reason of that is `j` is not in current scope, it's initiated when `int j =i+1` is executed.